# I want to write Javascript for an HTML5 canvas, but I don't know how to set the canvas up

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Up until now, I have only used Javascript in an environment that doesn't require any HTML, like the one on Khan Academy [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/new/pjs). However, now I'm using sublime text, and I realize that I can't just write ellipse() and have it show up on the screen. Now I need the  element. However, according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp), now, for a circle to show up, I need to do this:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

Ugh. I really don't want to have to write "ctx" before every single line of code I make, or learn a bunch of new commands like "beginPath" and "lineTo". Is there a way I can create the canvas, and still make a program without all this messy stuff? Or, if that's not possible, could someone point me to a library that can? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the question is. But from what I understood you need to learn how to add a canvas to a HTML file and link your JS to the same. If so, here's how to do it.

HTML as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Your Canvas Application</title>
  <!-- link your js file as below -->
  <script src = "path/to/yourjsfile.js">
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
```

JS file (yourjsfile.js) as below

```
window.onload = function () {
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
c.beginPath();
c.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
c.stroke();
};
```

You really can not entirely get rid of 'ctx', but instead you can shorten it for something like 'c'. Rather than looking for libraries, I recommend you learn the basics correct first. Then you can go ahead and explore the other options.

Answer (score 0):

While this approach still doesn't free you from the responsibility of knowing your way around the `canvas` element, you can make use of the `with` keyword to avoid continually typing `ctx` - the approach is not one I use and as per the MDN page [Statements and declarations>with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) you can run into problems with ambiguity.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
with (ctx)
  {
      beginPath();
      arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
      stroke();
  }
```

```html
<canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: Okay. So I get that the canvas element will be a little annoying at first. I have one more question: what does real Javascript look like? Does the ellipse() function actually not exist? Or is the ellipse() function only in certain libraries, and the actual Javascript that's happening behind the scenes is "ctx.arc..."?

Comment: Like any new object or concept in programming and in life, learning starts out a little slow and increases in speed as one becomes more familiar with the new environment.  (0) You'll know it as you see it more. (1) Nope, yep exactly - those libraries abstract away the complexities of the canvas and present different means (that rely on the native ones) to interact with it. MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) is a veritable source of information and more importantly, documentation. Here's a link you may find to be beneficial: [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Comment: The Khan Academy page you linked to uses the library [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) so you could potentially use that. Though I agree with others that it is worth learning to use canvas without it.